# proxy chains not compatable with google chrome or brave browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, proxy

whenever I run the command

```
proxychains google-chrome google.com
```

Or

```
proxychains brave-browser google.com
```

it returns an error right here:

```
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[0810/153758.884274:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/pepczenko/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/68c55cdd-398e-4a6d-ba15-e4acca253e46.lock: File exists (17)
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[0810/153759.204483:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/pepczenko/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/68c55cdd-398e-4a6d-ba15-e4acca253e46.lock: File exists (17)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

but only when i run it with firefox like this:

```
proxychains firefox google.com
```

Everything works fine and I think the issue is with chrome since brave browser is based on chrome I think thats why everything i weird anyways. If someone could help me out on this one it would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: You probably have to configure SOCKS proxy.

Comment: You probably ran this as `root` in the past. Check the ownership and permission of the file mentioned in the  `ERROR` messages.

Comment: @waltinator how can i Do that?

Comment: `file="filename"` Check with `sudo /bin/ls $file`. If it is owned by `root`, fix with `sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $file`.